# How to indicate first none missing value per subject in a longitudinal data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

```
id status age
1    1     NA
1    1     20
1    1     22
2    0     30
2    0     32
2    0     34
3    1     NA
3    1     NA
3    1     20
```

I want to index the element that `status=1` and the first non-missing value like below:

```
id status age  ind
1    1     NA   F
1    1     20   T
1    1     22   F
2    0     30   F
2    0     32   F
2    0     34   F
3    1     NA   F
3    1     NA   F
3    1     20   T
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- transform(dat, ind = status == 1 & ave(!is.na(age), 
                                              id, FUN = cumsum) == 1)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

```
  id status age   ind
1  1      1  NA FALSE
2  1      1  20  TRUE
3  1      1  22 FALSE
4  2      0  30 FALSE
5  2      0  32 FALSE
6  2      0  34 FALSE
```

Comment: I think this code works for this small data set but if you have a ID=3, status =1 and age (NA, 12,14,16), this code won't recognize it and will treat it as (F,F,F,F)

Answer (score 0):

`rle` to the rescue.

```
#example
Rgames> age<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3)

Rgames> rle(!is.na(age))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 2 3
  values : logi [1:2] FALSE TRUE

#now your dataframe
dat$ind<-rep(FALSE,nrow(dat)) 
datrle<- rle(!is.na(dat$age))
dat$ind[which(datrle$values)[1]] <- TRUE
```